# Firebase return child that have biggest value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase for a little while but I have stuck at one problem that I want to get the child that have the biggest value:

Example here's my json (edited manually):

```html
{
  "Players" : {
    "Scores" : {
      "-JFUIwudw93dkD" : {
        "rank" : 0
      },
      "-KSFOW833nSfkod" : {
        "rank" : 8
      },
      "-Kk5WfuJ8mlZTPdeUC40" : {
        "rank" : 2
      },
      "-SKKQuyhso83ds" : {
        "rank" : 14
      }
    }
  },
```

I need to get the child key for the highest rank.
So I need the "-SKKQuyhso83ds" child.

I have use this method but It doesn't work:

```
final DatabaseReference mDatabasePlayers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Players");
    Query mDatabaseHighestPlayer = mDatabasePlayers.child("Scores").orderByChild("rank").limitToFirst(1);
    mDatabaseHighestPlayer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            //This returns null
            String Key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(main.this,Key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}});
```

but that doesn't work so I'am waiting for some help brothers.

Comment: Check out this video- https://youtu.be/WeoryL3XyA4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase queries are ordered *ascending*. Since you order by rank and limit to the first result, you'll get the *lowest* score. To get the highest score, use `limitToLast(1)`.

In addition, when you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So in total:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabasePlayers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Players");
Query mDatabaseHighestPlayer = mDatabasePlayers.child("Scores").orderByChild("rank").limitToLast(1);
mDatabaseHighestPlayer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String Key = childSnapshot.getKey();
            Toast.makeText(main.this,Key,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't swallow errors
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
Query mDatabaseHighestPlayer = mDatabasePlayers.child("Scores").orderByChild("rank").limitToFirst(1);
```

with

```
Query mDatabaseHighestPlayer = mDatabasePlayers.child("Scores").child(scoreId).orderByChild("rank").limitToFirst(1);
```

In which `scoreId` is the unique id generated bu the `push()` method.